# How to count nodes in a Tree in R

Tags: r, tree

I'm starting to study ML with R. I do the following operations with RStudio:

```
iris=datasets::iris
tree(Species~., iris)
```

And I obtain:

```
 1) root 150 329.600 setosa ( 0.33333 0.33333 0.33333 )  
   2) Petal.Length < 2.45 50   0.000 setosa ( 1.00000 0.00000 0.00000 ) *
   3) Petal.Length > 2.45 100 138.600 versicolor ( 0.00000 0.50000 0.50000 )  
     6) Petal.Width < 1.75 54  33.320 versicolor ( 0.00000 0.90741 0.09259 )  
      12) Petal.Length < 4.95 48   9.721 versicolor ( 0.00000 0.97917 0.02083 )  
        24) Sepal.Length < 5.15 5   5.004 versicolor ( 0.00000 0.80000 0.20000 ) *
        25) Sepal.Length > 5.15 43   0.000 versicolor ( 0.00000 1.00000 0.00000 ) *
      13) Petal.Length > 4.95 6   7.638 virginica ( 0.00000 0.33333 0.66667 ) *
     7) Petal.Width > 1.75 46   9.635 virginica ( 0.00000 0.02174 0.97826 )  
      14) Petal.Length < 4.95 6   5.407 virginica ( 0.00000 0.16667 0.83333 ) *
      15) Petal.Length > 4.95 40   0.000 virginica ( 0.00000 0.00000 1.00000 ) *
```

My questions are:

1. how can I obtain the maximum node depth of the tree?
2. how can I obtain the number of nodes?

I use packages `tree` and `datasets`.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Which libraries are you using? Do you mean terminal nodes?

Comment: Sorry I didn't specify the packages. I use tree and datasets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Concerning your 2nd question you can do:

```
library(tree)

# build your tree
m = tree(Species~., iris)

# count how many times you have <leaf> in the models dataframe
sum(m$frame$var == "<leaf>")

# [1] 6

# count terminal nodes
length(unique(m$where))

# [1] 6

# count nodes
nrow(m$frame)

# [1] 11
```

Comment: I need the total number of nodes, not only the terminal  nodes

Comment: I've added that as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
tree:::tree.depth(as.integer(row.names(iris_tree$frame)))
## [1] 0 1 1 2 3 4 4 3 2 3 3
```

take `max()` of that for depth (+1 if not 0-indexing depth) and `length()` of that for # of nodes.

The above is what the package does internally